# Facebook sharing from mobile responsive website in iphone

Tags: php

I have developed one mobile responsive website. In which there us one button "Facebook". So now when user touch on facebook button (User can open webisite in iOS safari browser) then website link will be share on facebook.

I have tried googled but not got success.

Can you please give me guidance on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Share button using the Facebook API:

[Facebook Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

Comment: I want to implement when user click on facebook button (In mobile responsive website) then it should be open iOS native facebook application with sharing dialog. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understand well your original question. I'm not sure, in Android you can't by the moment, but I've no idea about iOS.